# Gmail bypass sending limit?

Tags: gmail

There seems to be a limit of 25 MB whenever I want to send files through Gmail.

Is there a way to remove (or bypass) this limit?

Comment: Many other email servers have a limit, so even if the gmail limit was lifted, you could still run into problems. But email is also a very inefficient way to send large files because of the way they are encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach the file to your Gmail message using Google Drive instead of as a traditional attachment, you can "send" files of up to **10 GB**. (You're not really sending a file but rather a link.)

From [Google Support](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/2480713):

> 1. Hover over the plus icon  at the bottom of the compose window, which will open the insert menu. (Remember, you need to be using [Gmail's new compose and reply experience](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=2645922) to insert files using Google Drive).
> 2. Click the Google Drive icon [image: Google Drive Icon]. In the window that appears, you can upload a file to Google Drive, as well as navigate to or search for files you've stored in Drive. For files stored in Drive, select the checkboxes next to the files you want to insert. *If you don't have any files in Drive, visit [drive.google.com](http://drive.google.com/) to either create, sync, or upload them.*
> 3. Click the **Insert** button.
>
> Gmail then adds a link to your message so recipients can click the link to view your file.
>
> When you send the message, Gmail checks to see if your recipients have access to the file and will prompt you to [adjust the sharing settings](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=2487407) on the file(s) you've inserted, if needed.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot change this limit.

If you want to store files in the cloud why not try using [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) or [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com)?

Comment: So go buy an MP3 on Amazon and get 20 GB free on Amazon's CloudDrive...

Comment: It is academic to get more storage on Dropbox. Plus, you can pay a more-than-reasonable rate for more storage.